# Alignment of text in column of table

Tags: css, oracle-adf

I have a table in my project which has alignment issue. Text are aligned in the center of the column but this alignment issue doesn't come up when I run the code in local. It only appears when I deploy the code on server.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jdeveloper are you using? This alignment issue was fixed in 11.1.2.4.0 release
Is your table having auto-PPR? This was causing the changes in alignment.

P.S: posted on answers than in comments section because I did not have reputation and wanted to communicate this to you.